# how to connect to more than 1 cassandra hosts using spark cassandra connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a spark application that reads data from one cassandra cluster and after some computation saves data to another cassandra cluster. I can set only 1 cassandra configuration in sparkconf. but I need to connect to 1 more cassandra cluster.

I see a CassandraConnector class that is used for connecting to cassandra but it uses CassandraConnectorConf object to create an object which takes a lot of parameters that I don't know.

Any assistance will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code :

```
SparkConf confForCassandra = new SparkConf().setAppName("ConnectToCassandra")
                .setMaster("local[*]")
                .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "<cassandraHost>");

CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(confForCassandra);

javaFunctions(rdd).writerBuilder("keyspace", "table", mapToRow(Table.class)).withConnector(connector).saveToCassandra();
```

Comment: It looks like you are only connecting to one cassandra host here. Where are you adding the other host? Is there a configuration file somewhere?

Comment: Do you mean that you create 2 SparkConf variables, one for each cassandra host, and then two different connector variables?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to connect to two Cassandra clusters using **Scala** and Spark, you can use the below code:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql._

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext


def twoClusterExample ( sc: SparkContext) = {
  val connectorToClusterOne = CassandraConnector(sc.getConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1"))
  val connectorToClusterTwo = CassandraConnector(sc.getConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.2"))

  val rddFromClusterOne = {
    // Sets connectorToClusterOne as default connection for everything in this code block
    implicit val c = connectorToClusterOne
    sc.cassandraTable("ks","tab")
  }

  {
    //Sets connectorToClusterTwo as the default connection for everything in this code block
    implicit val c = connectorToClusterTwo
    rddFromClusterOne.saveToCassandra("ks","tab")
  }

}
```

The original code was written by RusselSpitzer here: https://gist.github.com/RussellSpitzer/437f57dae4fd4bc4f32d

There is currently no way to do this with **Python** and Spark.